# Insert moments Where can I find the moments I had inserted?

Tags: insert, google-plus, where-clause

I had inserted a lots of moments by Google + php API.
These are my code.

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_ecret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $requestVisibleActions = array(
            'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
            'http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',
            'http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity');
    $client->setRequestVisibleActions($requestVisibleActions);
    $plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        //https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

    }


    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

        $moment_body = new Google_Moment();
        $moment_body->setType("http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity");

        $item_scope = new Google_ItemScope();
Zend_Log::INFO);
        $item_scope->setId('1343');
        $item_scope->setType("http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity");
        $item_scope->setType("http://schema.org/CreativeWork");

        $item_scope->setName("Test");
        $item_scope->setDescription(“This is just a test.”);

        $moment_body->setTarget($item_scope);

        $momentResult = $plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $moment_body);
```

The response is as follows:

`array(5) { ["kind"]=> string(11) "plus#moment" ["type"]=> string(40) "http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity" ["target"]=> array(4) { ["kind"]=> string(14) "plus#itemScope" ["id"]=> string(4) "1343" ["description"]=> string(20) "This is just a test." ["name"]=> string(4) "Test" } ["result"]=> array(1) { ["kind"]=> string(14) "plus#itemScope" } ["id"]=> string(75) "Eg0xMzc1NTE2ODc2MDYzGJGDxrC2ufClwgEyAhABQgYYofONXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }`

It seems that the moments is posted successfully. Right?

And the problem is  where I can see it.
I login on [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/). I didn't see the moment just inserted. Why?

Answer (score 0):

i'm wondering too why the moments are so hidden in google plus.

anyway, here is the link to all your authorized apps on google plus: https://plus.google.com/apps/
pick your app, you'll see the moments there.